# (wx)Maxima: does `makelist` work in parallel or serially?

Tags: list, recursion, maxima, wxmaxima

I am interested in creating a list whose terms are defined recursively (i.e. `term[i]` is a function of `term[i-1]`, *not* a function of `i-1`).

I figured that if `makelist` works serially, then calling a previous term should not be an issue; however, [the documentation](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_21.html#index-makelist) does not explicitly address how the terms are generated.

An initial attempt (NB: even though the output here could be achieved using a function of the index, the point was to create a simple example that tested the ability of calling previous terms, within `makelist`):

```
test:
makelist(block([ ], 
    
    /* list item set to 1 for first term of the list, and to previous list item, thereafter */  
    if i = 1 
    then addend 
    else test[i-1]
    )

, i, 5);
```

but this returns `[1, test[1], test[2], test[3], test[4] ]` so it doesn't seem to actually access the values of `test`.

I tried various experiments, including initializing `test`; including a call to test in the block, i.e. `block([ test:test ], ...` , and a few others, but haven't been able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question. The result of `makelist` isn't associated with the variable to which it is assigned (`test` in the example above) so while `makelist` is constructing its result, there is no way to know about `test[i - 1]` being the previous item. I don't think there is any way to access the previous item from within `makelist` (e.g. by some Lisp programming or something).

About `makelist` being serial or parallel, I'm 99% sure that elements are constructed in order. E.g. `makelist(print(i), i, 1, 10)` prints the numbers from 1 to 10.

If a term depends on the previous one, one way to do it is to create an empty list (e.g. `x: makelist(0, n)`) and then loop over the elements (e.g. `x[1]: FOO; for i:2 thru n do x[i]: x[i - 1] + something`).

Comment: Thanks Robert -- it's always interesting to learn more about the inner workings of Maxima! As always, greatly appreciate your taking the time to share your knowledge and insight!